# Query on generic display views - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

For the below url routing for `blog` app,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                    queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
                    template_name="blog/blog.html",
                   )
            )
]
```

template `blog.html` is,

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {%  for post in object_list %}
        <h5>{{post.date|date:"Y-m-d"}}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}"> {{post.title}} </a></h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

where model for `blog` app is defined as,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

MTV of `blog` app is structures as,

```
../blog
    admin.py
    apps.py
    __init__.py
    migrations
    models.py
    templates
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.p
```

---

**Question:**

`{{post.id}}` is internally created as primary key, for every row in the table,  but,

What does `/blog/{{post.id}}` mean in the template(`blog.html`)?

Comment: url to the detail of the post

Answer (score 1):

When you want to go to a particular blog, you need to have a link to that. That's what /blog/{{post.id}} does as a link.

so /blog/1 gives you the first blog. Only that you have to define the url pattern, the view and the template for that.

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[^/]+)/$', views.get_blog, name='one_blog'),
```

Then in views:

```
def get_blog(request, id):
    blog = Blogs.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'blogs/one_blog.html', locals())
```

And then in templates folder, create a 'blogs/one_blog.html' file. Simplest example being:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h5>{{blog.title}}</h5>
    {{blog.body}}
{% endblock %}
```

Just make sure that you understand the folder structure for templates.

Answer (score 1):

it's just a prefix /prefix/id/. It is also possible /article/1... it doesn't matter

urls.py

```
urlPatterns=[
      url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
                     model=Post,
                     template_name="blog/blog_list.html",
                   )
            )
      url(r'blog/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
                     model=Post,
                     template_name="blog/blog_detail.html",
                  )
            )

]
```